# 2.3 ratio between Pytorch BCEloss and my own "log" calculations

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm scripting a toy model to both practice PyTorch and GAN models, and I'm making sure I understand each step as much as possible.
That leaded me to checking my understanding of the BCEloss function, and apparently I understand it... with a ratio of 2.3.

To check the results, I write the intermediate values for Excel:

```
tmp1 = y_pred.tolist()  # predicted values in list (to copy/paste on Excel)
tmploss = nn.BCELoss(reduction='none')  # redefining a loss giving the whole BCEloss tensor
tmp2 = tmploss(y_pred, y_real).tolist()  # BCEloss values in list (to copy/paste Exel)
```

Then I copy `tmp1` on Excel and calculate: `-log(x)` for each values, which is the BCEloss formula for `y_target = y_real = 1`.

Then I compare the resulting values with the values of `tmp2`: these values are 2.3x higher than "mine".

[image]
(Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to format tables on this site...)

Can you please tell me what is happening? I feel a PEBCAK coming :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in Excel the **Log** function calculates the logarithm to the base 10.
The standard definition of binary cross entropy uses a log function to the base **e**.
The ratio you're seeing is just *log(10)=2.302585*

Comment: Thank you!
My problem was actually that I never learned that "log" could mean "ln". Anyway: PEBCAK, as it was easy to figured out yet I missed it :-(